# Make Command Not Found

Tags: command-line, bash, make, zsh

I am having a problem that doesn't seem to be common based on searching various forums.

I cannot run the Make command.

Message:

```
The program 'make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install make
```

So do this:

```
sudo apt-get install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
make is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

But then when I try to run Make I get the same message.  What's up?

Edit: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit Desktop fresh install.

Answer (score 176):

Run this command to **install make** and all the packages needed to build your code.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: also installs `cc` which was the next command missing.

Comment: Question from 2012 and answer from 2016, so had to check, but indeed still solves it in 2022 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 73):

Probably it is due command make is not present in system PATH, so remove and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall make
```

Answer (score 12):

Run command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update package lists. After this,

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should update your packages and then install "make".

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make
```

Answer (score 0):

I was coming from a background of installing WSL2 just today and was surprised to find that packages like make weren't already there, as I was so used to them being.

Then I realized my Ubuntu is a bit of a "clean slate". So I decided to update it to get essential development packages as per 'standard' recommendation, I guess:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/wsl2/

Edit: Install pip, too!

Answer (score 0):

Run

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

Before running make, you might also need to generate a Makefile first.

Run

> ./configure

Then the make command