# Can’t get Thermal Printer Drivers to Install

Tags: drivers, printing

I’m having a lot of trouble trying to get my thermal printer to work with Ubuntu.  I’m new to Linux and my driver is in a .zip. It not only has a PPD file but also has a raster-tspl filter file. I can’t find any info on how to install it and to get my printer working. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does the thermal printer have any instructions for how to install the driver(s)?

Comment: Not that I can see unless I’m missing something

Comment: Hmm. If you don't mind, what thermal printer is it?

Comment: @cocomac it is often a label printer or a barcode printer used in different types of production.

Comment: iDPRT SF410 label printer

Comment: @Johnfarmer I think I found the driver. Is [this one](https://www.idprt.com/downloads/modelid/41/classifyid/22/type/1.html) it? Sadly, the utility [is Windows only](https://www.idprt.com/downloads/modelid/41/classifyid/23/type/1.html)

Comment: the driver from their website is 1.4.2 you need to unzip it and look in the install instructions.it is the linux driver.

Comment: @trondhansen The instructions just look like a bunch of gibberish code to me… not sure what to do with it

Comment: After unzipping all you need to do is (1) make `install` script executable (easiest way is roght-click > properties and select that option) and (2) run it with `sudo ./install` (assuming you're already in the unzipped folder; give the full path otherwise).

Comment: @Johnfarmer i am not sure how to run the install script it is way over my head,i guess you need hands on help to install it.this is the driver file https://www.idprt.com/prt_v2/files/down_file/id/131/fid/431 if anybody here can help tell you how it is done.

Comment: @trondhansen There's really nothing else to it then what I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @ChanganAutoWould you be able to elaborate as to how to run the sudo install? Trying to use the command in terminal but getting command not found. Sorry I am very new to Ubuntu. I really appreciate your help

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1386052/1210606